# how to ssh into a lxc-container

Tags: debian, sshd, lxc, container

I need a user that connects to my host with ssh, which is forwarded into a lxc-container.

My solution is:

```
Match User monitoring 
ChrootDirectory /data/foreign_projects/monitoring 
ForceCommand lxc-console -n monitoring_lxc
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. To get to your question, [please edit your post to include additional context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/502996/edit). What is the exact issue you are having? Please include details about how you set up your lxc-container and what is the intended outcome and any _exact_ error messages that you get. Thank you!

Comment: You'll want to use the ForceCommand option to run a command to connect the user to the container.

Comment: @StephenHarris If i use the ForceCommand, can the user exit the lxc?

Comment: When they exit the container, they will return to your script, which can then `exit` and log them out.